# Convert a date to Date.now() like format in iavascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I need to convert a date to "Date.now()" like format in `javascript`. For eg. using `Date.now()`, I'm getting the value as `1395150601449`. I need my date to be formatted like this.  How can I achieve this ? I would like to create a custom filter in `angularjs` for this formatting.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would probably have taken you less time to simply consult [some reliable documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Stackoverflow should not be the first resource you use for such simple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `.getTime()` function.

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTime());
```

You can do the opposite by passing such a timestamp to the Date constructor. Thus, to make a copy of a date instance:

```
var copy = new Date( d.getTime() );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How to get the date object from this value ? I mean the reverse operation. (I'm new to these technologies and hence the silly questions. :))

Comment: @AnishV you can pass a timestamp (one of those numbers) as the argument to the Date constructor. I will extend the answer with an example.